# Do something after user is Logged- Firebase Angular2

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular2-template, angular2-services

I want to know on my app-component when the user is logged and then to console.log user email. But the problem is that the operation to load app.component is faster then to get info from Firebase server. So I want to get the user email only after I know he is logged.
I am talking for automatically logging after refresh of browser not logging after click the button.
I think I need to do it with Observable or Promise but I am not sure which Firebase method to use.

Comment: I made it with setTimeout() function but I know this is not the right way to do it because the data from server can slow more then 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you please post more code of your this.userService object? The getEmail function there should return either an observable or a promise, if it doesn't already.

Comment: @PetkoKamenov Post the method that does performs the login. Sounds like the code you mention must be executed as a callback on the login action.

Comment: Here is my Login function in UsersService
` login(email: string, password: string): firebase.Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }`

Comment: I don't wanna know when is logged after clicking the button. I want to know it on every refresh on my site because the browser remember when I am logged

Comment: From what I understand, `AngularFireAuth.auth` returns an initialized `firebase.auth.Auth` instance. That means you can [hook into `onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) to detect when the user has signed in (or out).